# WPF doesn't always repaint when using WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, winforms, paint, managed-directx, windowsformshost

I have a simple application which is hosting a Managed DirectX `Control` using `WindowsFormsHost`. I've overridden the paint methods in the `Control` to prevent flicker:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visible == true) { base.OnPaint(e); }
}

// Don't paint the background unless the control is not visible
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visible == false) { base.OnPaintBackground(e); }
}
```

There is a timer which periodically invalidates the Managed DirectX `Control` so that it will be redrawn.

My problem is that when I lock the computer (WIN+L), and then unlock it, the WPF content around the `WindowsFormsHost` occasionally does not get fully painted. Various portions of it are not drawn until I drag the window completely out of view. Any ideas on why WPF doesn't finish repainting itself?

Apologies if this is too vague to solve the issue, I'm unable to share more source code.

Comment: Change to SlimDX and ditch the WindowsFormsHost. There are tons of web posts about mixing SlimDX with WPF (including numerous items on StackOverflow). Managed DirectX is dead. And good riddance, I say...